# Best graphics card for Blender Cycles rendering

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I want to build a system with a graphics card that can render scenes fast. I have heard people saying gtx 780 ti is great because of its high cuda cores. Im not sure what I should go for. Also what would be a good processor to handle such graphics card?

Comment: Questions on hardware recommendations are considered off topic. Those questions are better answered in http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ or on the technical support forum [blenderartists.org](https://blenderartists.org/forum/forumdisplay.php?44-Technical-Support)

Comment: There is no way to answer this correctly. It all depends on your needs: the kind of scenes you'll be rendering and how much money you have to spend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is hard to say, because there are not relevant benchmark for cycles. (If someone know one, please let us know).

You can look at http://blenchmark.com/gpu-benchmarks. Keep in mind than this is not accurate results, because results are affected by CPU speed quite enough.

And yes, you are right: more CUDA cores are better for Cycles. "x80" and "Ti" have also wider bus (384bits) and that is the reason why 780 is little bit faster than 970 (with 256bits) in rendering. But 780 have almost double power consumption. Good for 970 is also 4GB RAM.

In my opinion the best what you can do is buy one GTX 970 now and second one (or better) later. In Blender you can use multiple CUDA card and can be different.

Comment: although i'm commenting too late, but for new readers. 970 is not with 4GB that is 3.5GB. That doesn't make any difference as compare to 3GB or 780 and 3.5GB of 970. it's better you get 2 older 780 ti in sli if you can't buy two 970 in sli.. still 780tiSli is better then 970sli

Answer (score 0):

The 780ti is quite old now. Nvidia has just released the 10x0 series, and as a result the 9x0 (eg 980ti) are quite cheap now. For hobby use, a single card is fine. I've got the gtx970 and it motors along quite well.

If you're doing heavy work and have lots of money, SLI (multi-gpu) setups can be used.

While the 780ti and 970 are about the same speed, the 970 is cheaper, more power-efficient. [Source](http://gpuboss.com/gpus/GeForce-GTX-970-vs-GeForce-GTX-780-Ti)

Comment: please don't run gpu's in SLI for Blender.